# How to center UIImageView within UIButton with its text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton`, and im adding an image like so:

```
UIImageView *cardImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Visa.png"]];
cardImage.frame = CGRectMake(15, _cardButton.frame.size.height - 25 - 10, 25, 25);
cardImage.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[_cardButton addSubview:cardImage];
```

How can i show this image centered WITH the titleLable of the `UIButton`?

Answer (score 0):

// try like this

```
cardImage.frame = _cardButton.frame;
cardImage.center = _cardButton.center;
cardImage.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on Its may be helpful to you

```
CGFloat flotspacing = 50; // the amount of spacing to appear between image and title
Btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, flotspacing);
Btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, flotspacing, 0, 0);
```

and also try this code with .h and .m file

**UIButton+BtnPosition.h**

```
@interface UIButton(ImageTitleCentering)

 -(void) centerButtonPositionAndImageWithSpacing:(CGFloat)spacing;

@end
```

**UIButton+BtnPosition.m**

```
  @implementation UIButton(ImageTitleCentering)

     -(void) centerButtonPositionAndImageWithSpacing:(CGFloat)spacing {
         self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, spacing);
         self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, spacing, 0, 0);
     }
```

@end

Now call this function with following

```
  [button centerButtonPositionAndImageWithSpacing:10];
```

I use this coding for set button image and title in center it may be helpful to you.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding imageview as subview of UIButton, try to set image with button image property.

```
// the space between the image and text
    CGFloat spacing = 6.0;

    // lower the text and push it left so it appears centered 
    //  below the image
    CGSize imageSize = button.imageView.image.size;
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
      0.0, - imageSize.width, - (imageSize.height + spacing), 0.0);

    // raise the image and push it right so it appears centered
    //  above the text
    CGSize titleSize = [button.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: button.titleLabel.font}];
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
      - (titleSize.height + spacing), 0.0, 0.0, - titleSize.width);

    // increase the content height to avoid clipping
    CGFloat edgeOffset = fabsf(titleSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0;
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(edgeOffset, 0.0, edgeOffset, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to add `UIImageView` as subview to `UIButton`. `UIButton` is having `BackgroundImage` and `Image` property to set your image to button. Set the `contentMode` property to `center` to center the image.

```
_cardButton.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

If `image` looks too big in the `UIButton`, reduce the size of the `image` or ask your designer to give the image with required `Padding`.

Comment: But im not trying to make it into a background image.